# Modifying a Stock ROM

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, stock-android, customization, stock-rom

I'm an Android newbie who has a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 7" Wifi (SM-T210) and would like to retrieve its stock ROM, modify certain files and add some applications to the system partition, and then flash it into any other SM-T210 device. Is this possible? How can I do it?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The second half is not the big deal. The first half is. To retrieve it, you'd need a custom recovery. So after that, it's most likely not stock anymore...

Comment: @Izzy No, he can retrieve it using ADB. Like `adb pull /system` for the ROM. Custom recoveries take a backup of *everything*, including data, which I think is not what @Storo wants to get flashed as well.

Comment: Apart from the fact that `adb pull` wouldn't have access to *everything* without root: how to get that back to the "other device" then? Don't try `adb push`, won't work without root ("read-only file system"). Storo explicitely wrote *flash it into any other SM-T210 device*, which means he needs an image, if I'm not getting things wrong here. // However, that's a pretty grey area for this site, very close to "building a custom ROM" (one of our closure-reasons).

Comment: Hmm, you're right. It's possible to get a firmware image from [SamMobile](http://sammobile.com/firmwares) and extract it using some ext4 imaging tool. Also, flashing on "any other X device" may either refer to using recovery (which is more likely) or using firmware flash tools, like Odin.